# How to take user input, and then run a CMD command using that input? (BATCH)

Tags: batch-file

I'm making some "Private" programs using Batch, and wan't a user to input an Internet Protocal into the batch input, and then when you hit enter, it takes that input, and runs a ping command on that IP? How would one go across such thing?

~ Husky

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40764103/edit) your question and post what did you tried as code so far !

Comment: `set /p input=input something`  ??

Comment: @Hackoo I didn't post what I tried as I've been scoping the internet for it but can't find SIMPLY explained things, I also am not "Secure" enough to post it as it has quite a bit of personal info (My IP ect)

Comment: set /p input=ping 
start cmd.exe /k ping
goto Main
pause                                         Thats what I have so far, I need the "cmd.exe /k ping" to have the input after it.

Comment: @Husky Please take a look here to learn how to mark the answer as accepted [Help Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

As all others allready stated in the comments you are looking for

```
set /p myVariable= Asking for value here
```

You can then use this variable enclosing it within `%` ->

```
ping %myVariable%
```

should do the trick. You do not neccessarily need the `start cmd.exe /k` but you can use it.

Feel free to ask questions!

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this sample batch :

```bat
@echo off
Title Ping hosts tester 
:PingLoop
Color 0A & cls
echo Type the host IP to get info about its ping
set /p "IP=> "
ping %IP%
echo.
echo Hit any key to continue for another IP ...
pause>nul
Goto :PingLoop
```

***EDIT : To check and validate the ip address entred by user before the pinging***

```bat
@echo off
Title Check IP and Ping tester
:Main
cls & color 0E
echo Type your IP address :
Set /p "IP="
Call :CheckValidIP %IP%
cls
IF "%errorlevel%" EQU "0" ( 
    cls
    Color 0A
    echo %IP% is valid 
    Ping %IP%
    echo.
    echo Hit any key to continue for another IP ...
    pause>nul & Goto Main
) else (
    cls
    Color 0C
    echo %IP% is not valid
    echo Hit any key to continue for another IP ...
    pause>nul
)
Goto Main
::*********************************************************************************
:CheckValidIP <IP>
(
echo If IsValidIP("%~1"^) = True Then
echo    Wscript.Quit(0^)
echo Else
echo    Wscript.Quit(1^)
echo End If
echo Function IsValidIP(IPAddress^)
echo    Dim objRegExpr
echo    Set objRegExpr = New RegExp
echo    objRegExpr.Pattern = "\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d?\d)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d?\d)\b"
echo    objRegExpr.Global = True
echo    objRegExpr.IgnoreCase = False
echo    IsValidIP = objRegExpr.Test(IPAddress^)
echo    Set objRegExpr = Nothing
echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Why this overkill?! This is to much in my oppinion and hard to understand if you just started with batch. `goto`s CScript and writing vbs from within the batch-script. Further you are not even attempting to explain what is going on...

Comment: Why not simply use `findstr /r` to check the IP instead of all this VBS stuff?